# Is it possible to define SensitivityClassification for database columns by using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to define `SensitivityClassification` for database columns by using Entity Framework? For example:

```
HasSensitivityClassification = Confidential
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20302

Comment: @GertArnold HasSensitivityClassification not available

Comment: Yeah, it's an open issue.